How can I search within Helm results?
Is it possible to further narrow the results, by searching within the results?
I've found a few references to saving the results and then searching that, but that seems a little tedious.
I know that I can add search terms with a space, but this requires that the second term comes after the first term
So "hit solo", will not match
solo/hit
